# what is the best practice for connecting to the database and manipulating data?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

some people said one connection per each request
and some others said to create one connection and use it for each request.

I think if we want to create one connection per request the number of requests that we can handle each time depends on our database.

and if we want to create one connection for all requests we should always check our connection is alive.

for example, in FastApi documentation, they said to use this code for access to the database.

```py
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

and my problem is when I send a lot of async requests to my application in some requests I got `sorry, too many clients already` error because of the number of connections that I can make to Postgres.

I know I can change the pool_size like this in sqlarchmy

```py
engine = create_engine(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_size=200, max_overflow=0)
```

but is it a good way to fix my problem?

Comment: In this a way we can do. But this is not a good way every time. Because when using cloud solution they charge for number of db connections. That means more pool size is not every time a best option.

Comment: Maintaining db and rest api in same network (example: both db and api in same instance or vpc) a good way. Because when we do that network I/O (traffic) is low. Then it not take much lower time receive results from db instance.  That mean it increase the availability of connection of pool in particular time.

Comment: Reducing number of queries make. example: for a particular request we need to take customer data. but the customer address in 1 table and telephone num in another table. If we take these data using 2 queries we need 2 connection from pool. otherwise we can make a join query and get that data from 1 query. It reduce num of need db connection to 1. This also a good option.

Comment: The only good way to use a database is with a connection pool.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you explain?

Comment: That requires a tutorial - try a web search for "connection pool".